# Nvidia driver not working on Ubuntu 20.04 with GeForce RTX 3060

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-settings

I've been trying for a while now to install the Nvidia drivers in my laptop, but even though it seems to be installed the nvidia commands doesn't work at all nor the HDMI displays works with an external screen (via HDMI).

The command:

```
nvidia-smi
```

gives the following output:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

And the:

```
nvidia-settings
```

gives the following output, even thoug,it opens the Nvidia X Server Settings :

> ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
>
> ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

I don't have much experience with ubuntu, but I've managed to follow almost everything I found to install them going through:

1. Install using "Software & updates" --> "Additional Drivers" and selecting the one is recommended by the `ubuntu-drivers devices`.
2. Install using `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470` and also `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
3. Downloading the latest version for ubuntu from the Nvidia official page (last release september 20 if I'm not wrong)

**Nothing has solved the issue and I can't change to the Nvidia graphic card (in "Settings" --> "About" --> "Graphics" appears the intel card "Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2)") nor use the nvidia commands**

My laptop specs are the following:

- Laptop: MSI GF65 Thin 10UE
- CPU: Intel Core i5-10500H Processor
- GPU: GeForce RTX3060/6GB GDDR6
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
  And using:
  ´´´
  uname -s -r
  ´´´
  I get:

> Linux 5.11.0-36-generic

***I will appreciate so much any kind of advice or help because I'm totally lost here, I don't know what else to do... :/***

PS. I tried installing the 18.04 ubuntu version and it didn't work it neither

THANK YOU A LOT IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI, that's all (or use `mokutil` to manually sign the Nvidia drivers - not recommended for beginners).

Comment: Done that, but still same problem!! Which is the next possible problem with the drivers??

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: disabling secure boot makes my gui disrupted / lines / grains etc. and not able to operate the system.